# iFrame redirecting & reload homepage issue on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, jquery-mobile

I have an `iframe` that's supposed to auto reload after 30 sec, but it only works on my pc browser, not on mobile. After I added a regex to test the User Agent, it's still not working on mobile.

Here is the mobile code:

```javascript
var regex = /android|(iP(hone|ad))/i;
if(regex.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);
    function reloadIFrame() {
        document.getElementById("test").src="http://example.com";
    }
    if (true) {
        top.getElementById("test").src;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("test").src;
    }
}
```

Iframe Code:

```
<iframe id="test" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

I want it to work it on mobile. Please help me to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: no one here to help me sir...?

Comment: please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Your `iframe` is set to `display:none`, so it won't ever be visible
2. You pass a string to `setInterval`, but it expects a function reference.

Try this:

```javascript
var regex = /android|(iP(hone|ad))/i;
if(regex.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    window.setInterval(reloadIFrame, 1000);
    function reloadIFrame() {
        document.getElementById("test").src="https://example.com";
    }
    if (true) {
        top.getElementById("test").src;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("test").src;
    }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="test"></iframe>
```